# Use a precompiled plugin (via a shared library) in a QML application

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML plugin compiled (to a `.so`) by [another project](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/qt). I want to re-use this in my own QML application without re-building it each time. I want to copy the `.so` over and, with minimal additional code, be able to write:

`import QQuickMapboxGL 1.0`

at the top of my QML files and have it work.

**Where do I need to copy the `.so` in my QML project, and how do I need to add it to the project so that the QML runtime can find it?**

---

What I've tried:

1. Create a `QQuickMapboxGL` directory with `libqmapboxgl.so` in it.
2. Create a `qmldir` file in that directory with the contents:

   ```
   plugin qmapboxgl
   ```
3. Add the following to my `.pro` file:

   ```sh
   INSTALL_DIR = $$PWD/../install
   target.path = $$INSTALL_DIR

   # Copy the QQuickMapboxGL folder to the install directory
   plugin.files = QQuickMapboxGL/*
   plugin.path  = $$INSTALL_DIR/QQuickMapboxGL

   INSTALLS += target plugin
   ```
4. Add a `make install` build step.

The result of this mad hackery was:

```
plugin cannot be loaded for module "QQuickMapboxGL": Plugin verification data mismatch in '/my/build/QQuickMapboxGL/libqmapboxgl.so'
```

I have verified that the plugin and my application are both being compiled with the same version of g++ (`g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904`) and the same Qt download (5.7.0).

Comment: What this library is? A QML plugin?

Comment: @folibis Yes. It is `QQuickMapboxGL` from [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/qt/README.md).

Comment: I guess the path should be 'appPath/imports/pluginName/plugin.dll'

Comment: [Creating C++ Plugins for QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) - [Writing QML Extensions with C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html)

Comment: @Redanium Did you forget to add your comment after providing those links? Was there a particular piece of information you were suggesting, beyond "RTFM"? The [plugin has already been created](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/qt/include/qmapboxgl.hpp). I'm asking about a specific error when attempting to include it in my project. Is there something relevant in either of those links that I'm missing?

Comment: To be fair, the title is a bit cryptic. For one, QML has no notion of .so files. It's more like you are having problems running a QML plugin in a different project.

Comment: @ddriver If you feel that another title is more appropriate, please feel free to edit it. (You have the rep! :) As may be evident, I'm new to managing projects with Qt Creator, or developing using QML and shared libraries.

Comment: @Phrogz - sure, I have the rep, but you do as well. You might be a babe in the qml woods, but you should not be stranger to common sense. A QML plugin is just one of the numerous things a shared library could be. Not to mention the qmldir and the extra info it carries.

Comment: @ddriver Fair enough. I've done my best to derive a better title, based on your comments. (No, I didn't realize that a QML shared library could be more than a plugin. And authoring the `qmldir` file as I did above has been my first time creating one.)

Comment: QML itself has no notion of shared libraries, or anything C++, it only knows only whatever the qtquick runtime exposes to it. It goes without saying, that a properly implemented plugin should work straight away, given the host project is binary compatible, however, with Qt it is not always smooth sailing.

Comment: As your error message suggests the plugin library is found and has been attempted to load, but its meta data does not match what the plugin loader expects. E.g. built with a different Qt (version or build configuration) or a different compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the `.so` is not a QML Plugin; no class inherits from `QQmlExtensionPlugin` or related. It is just a shared library of code.

Was able to workaround this by:

- Adding the header files for MapboxGL to my project
- In my `main.cpp`:

  - `#include "3rdparty/mapbox-gl-native/platform/qt/include/qmapbox.hpp"`
  - Calling `QMapbox::registerTypes();` (inside `main`)
- Copying `libmapboxgl.so` (built via Mapbox's make/cmake) inside a `libs` directory.
- In `myproject.pro` adding: `LIBS += -L./libs -lqmapboxgl`
- In my QML code `import QQuickMapboxGL 1.0` and then using `MapboxMap`
- Copying `libmapboxgl.so` to somewhere that is referenced by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`